# image data augmentation using Image Data generator in keras

Tags: python, image, tensorflow, deep-learning, image-preprocessing

I am currently working in a project on computer vision and I wanted to use the image data generator to load my images according to classes from respective directories so .

I wanted to augment my images by `feature_std_normalization`

I declared the feature_std_normalization=True while creating the data generator object but while training it is giving an error:

> local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras_preprocessing/image/image_data_generator.py:716: UserWarning: This ImageDataGenerator specifies `featurewise_center`, but it hasn't been fit on any training data. Fit it first by calling `.fit(numpy_data)`. warnings.warn('This ImageDataGenerator specifies '

how to use `dategen.fit ()` while  images are coming from `generator.flow_from_directory()` as `datagen.fit()` is using  `X_train` and i dont have it

Answer (score 0):

If you're using TensorFlow 2, then there are two approaches you could try:

1. Using `.flow_from_directory()`: as [the docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator) say, you can actually just pass in the path to the directory holding your images, and then your `datagen` object is ready to be passed to `model.fit()`. Here is the example that's provided in the TensorFlow documentation I linked above (with some additional comments for clarity):

```
# Set the augmentations the data generators will do
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        rescale=1./255,
        shear_range=0.2,
        zoom_range=0.2,
        horizontal_flip=True)
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
# Instantiate a DirectoryIterator - this yields the batches of data samples + their labels
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        'data/train',
        target_size=(150, 150),
        batch_size=32,
        class_mode='binary')
validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        'data/validation',
        target_size=(150, 150),
        batch_size=32,
        class_mode='binary')
# Train a Sequential model
model.fit(
        train_generator,
        steps_per_epoch=2000,
        epochs=50,
        validation_data=validation_generator,
        validation_steps=800)
```

2. Using `tf.data.Dataset.from_generator`: this approach might be more convenient for you if you want to take advantage of the `tf.data` API, and your dataset hasn't already been split into training and test sets. Here's an example (from a different page in the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data)) of how it works:

```
# This example uses an image dataset that has NOT been split into train/test yet
flowers = tf.keras.utils.get_file(
    'flower_photos',
    'https://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/example_images/flower_photos.tgz',
    untar=True)
# Like before, set the data augmentations
img_gen = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255, rotation_range=20)
# (Optional) Double-check the dimensions of a single batch
images, labels = next(img_gen.flow_from_directory(flowers))
print(images.dtype, images.shape)  # float32 (32, 256, 256, 3)
print(labels.dtype, labels.shape)  # float32 (32, 5)
# Now, you can make a dataset with the augmentations
ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
    lambda: img_gen.flow_from_directory(flowers), 
    output_types=(tf.float32, tf.float32), 
    output_shapes=([32,256,256,3], [32,5])
)
```

Of course, you might still be wondering, "how are we going to split this `ds` variable into training and test sets?"

Fortunately, Angel Igareta has written a great [blog post](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-split-a-tensorflow-dataset-into-train-validation-and-test-sets-526c8dd29438) on this topic. Below I will include just the code snippet that solves our problem:

```
def get_dataset_partitions_tf(ds, ds_size, train_split=0.8, val_split=0.1, test_split=0.1, shuffle=True, shuffle_size=10000):
    """Credit to Angel Igareta at https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-split-a-tensorflow-dataset-into-train-validation-and-test-sets-526c8dd29438 for this code."""
    assert (train_split + test_split + val_split) == 1
    
    if shuffle:
        # Specify seed to always have the same split distribution between runs
        ds = ds.shuffle(shuffle_size, seed=12)
    
    train_size = int(train_split * ds_size)
    val_size = int(val_split * ds_size)
    
    train_ds = ds.take(train_size)    
    val_ds = ds.skip(train_size).take(val_size)
    test_ds = ds.skip(train_size).skip(val_size)
    
    return train_ds, val_ds, test_ds
```

In this way, you will be able to pass your dataset to `model.fit()`, and TensorFlow will essentially *do the data augmentations for you* as it trains.

Last but not least - in your case, I believe you'll want to pass `featurewise_std_normalization=True` to the `ImageDataGenerator` constructor. Let me know if I missed something in your question, but I don't think there actually is a parameter named `feature_std_normalization` for it.